# how to select every 1st 2nd 3rd .... nth

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, if-statement, foreach

simply i wanted to do this for a wordpress loop and i want the fallowing result.

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        //
        // Post Content here
        //
    } // end while
} // end if
?>

<div class="List-Module">
  <div class="List-Module-Big">TITLE OF POST#1</div>
  <div class="List-Module-Grid">
    <div class="List-Module-Grid-Item">TITLE OF POST#2</div>
    <div class="List-Module-Grid-Item">TITLE OF POST#3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="List-Module-Item">TITLE OF POST#4</div>
  <div class="List-Module-Big">TITLE OF POST#5</div>
  <div class="List-Module-Grid">
    <div class="List-Module-Grid-Item">TITLE OF POST#6</div>
    <div class="List-Module-Grid-Item">TITLE OF POST#7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="List-Module-Item">TITLE OF POST#8</div>
</div>

//loops all through 32 items
```

as you see 1n, 2n, 3n and 4n posts results have to be in different classes. Can you help?

Comment: Are these given intervals? Every 4th entry gets the same class?

Comment: yes. A loop echos 30 results. i want to devide them group of 4 and put each items of group in differend divs.

Comment: Do you want 4 divs, with classes A through D, with all the elements, or have a dive before each entry? Your code-snippet is ambigious and isn't quite clear on that.

Comment: i just updated the code to exact result i desired

Comment: Use the modulus operator `%` and check the remainder. Give it a go ;-)

Comment: you may want to update the question to include the PHP part as well. Look into array_chunk() - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: Would it suffice to use the CSS nth-child pseudo-class? You can give that a formula, e.g. `:nth-child(5n)` would select the 5th, 10th, etc. childen.

Comment: my aim is to add different div structure not just styling.